# How to define a middle line in a window and align all elements to this line

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

The title question may be phrased not well, but I can show you an image and you'll know what I mean:

[image]

As you see the layout of top and bottom panels should be independent from the centering.

I tried to achieve this with `BoxLayout` for the main `Panel` and `GridBagLayout` for the single `Panel`s separated with `JSeparator`. But I have some difficulties about that. I won't complain about these difficulties, but I just want get some help making this (simple) layout.

Here's a SSCCE of my current state:

```
public class GridBagLayoutProblem extends JFrame
{

    private final JTextArea generatorTextArea;
    private JTextArea message1TextArea;
    private JTextArea message2TextArea;
    private JButton loadButton;
    private JButton browseButton;
    private JButton saveButton;
    private JTextField solution1TextField;
    private JTextField solution2TextField;
    private JCheckBox questionCheckBox;
    private JTextField locationTextField;
    public GridBagLayoutProblem()
    {
        super("GridBagLayout Problem SSCCE");

        // Build GUI
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        // Prepare Layouts
        final BoxLayout bLayout = new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);

        final Insets horizInsets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
        final Insets horizVertInsets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        final Insets generatorTextAreaInsets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 24);
        final Insets message1TextAreaInsets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 64);
        final Insets message2TextAreaInsets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 64);
        final Insets buttonMarginInsets = new Insets(-1, 0, -2, 0);

        setLayout(bLayout);

        // Exercise loading panel
        final JPanel eLoadPanel = new JPanel();
        final GridBagLayout gbLayout_eLoadPanel = new GridBagLayout();
        eLoadPanel.setLayout(gbLayout_eLoadPanel);

        final JTextField matNrTextField = new JTextField();
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_matNrTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_matNrTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_matNrTextField.gridx = 0;
        gbc_matNrTextField.gridy = 0;
        gbc_matNrTextField.weightx = 1;
        gbc_matNrTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 210, 0, 0);
        eLoadPanel.add(matNrTextField, gbc_matNrTextField);

        loadButton = new JButton("Load/Unload");
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_loadButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_loadButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc_loadButton.gridx = 1;
        gbc_loadButton.gridy = 0;
        gbc_loadButton.weightx = 0;
        gbc_loadButton.weighty = 0;
        gbc_loadButton.insets = horizVertInsets;
        loadButton.setMargin(buttonMarginInsets);
        eLoadPanel.add(loadButton, gbc_loadButton);

        add(eLoadPanel);

        add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));

        // Generator Polynom Panel
        final JPanel generatorPanel = new JPanel();
        final GridBagLayout gbLayout_generatorPanel = new GridBagLayout();
        generatorPanel.setLayout(gbLayout_generatorPanel);

        final JLabel generatorLabel = new JLabel("Generatorpolynom: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_generatorLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_generatorLabel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_generatorLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_generatorLabel.gridy = 0;
        gbc_generatorLabel.weightx = 0;
        gbc_generatorLabel.insets = horizVertInsets;
        generatorPanel.add(generatorLabel, gbc_generatorLabel);

        generatorTextArea = new JTextArea();
        generatorTextArea.setEditable(false);
        generatorTextArea.setFocusable(false);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_generatorTextArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_generatorTextArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_generatorTextArea.gridx = 1;
        gbc_generatorTextArea.gridy = 0;
        gbc_generatorTextArea.weightx = 0;
        gbc_generatorTextArea.insets = generatorTextAreaInsets;
        generatorPanel.add(generatorTextArea, gbc_generatorTextArea);

        add(generatorPanel);

        add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));

        // Task1 Panel - Calculate transferred message
        final JPanel task1Panel = new JPanel();
        final GridBagLayout gbLayout_task1Panel = new GridBagLayout();
        task1Panel.setLayout(gbLayout_task1Panel);

        final JLabel message1Label = new JLabel("Die zu übertragende Nachricht: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_message1Label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_message1Label.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_message1Label.gridx = 0;
        gbc_message1Label.gridy = 0;
        gbc_message1Label.weightx = 0;
        gbc_message1Label.insets = horizVertInsets;
        task1Panel.add(message1Label, gbc_message1Label);

        message1TextArea = new JTextArea();
        message1TextArea.setEditable(false);
        message1TextArea.setFocusable(false);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_message1TextArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_message1TextArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_message1TextArea.gridx = 1;
        gbc_message1TextArea.gridy = 0;
        gbc_message1TextArea.weightx = 0;
        gbc_message1TextArea.insets = message1TextAreaInsets;
        task1Panel.add(message1TextArea, gbc_message1TextArea);

        final JLabel solution1Label = new JLabel("Übertragene Nachricht inkl. redundante Bits: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_solution1Label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_solution1Label.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_solution1Label.gridx = 0;
        gbc_solution1Label.gridy = 1;
        gbc_solution1Label.weightx = 0;
        gbc_solution1Label.insets = horizVertInsets;
        task1Panel.add(solution1Label, gbc_solution1Label);

        solution1TextField = new JTextField();
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_solution1TextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_solution1TextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_solution1TextField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_solution1TextField.gridy = 1;
        gbc_solution1TextField.insets = message1TextAreaInsets;
        gbc_solution1TextField.weightx = 1; // important
        task1Panel.add(solution1TextField, gbc_solution1TextField);

        add(task1Panel);

        add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));

        // Task 2 Panel -
        final JPanel task2Panel = new JPanel();
        final GridBagLayout gbLayout_task2Panel = new GridBagLayout();
        task2Panel.setLayout(gbLayout_task2Panel);

        final JLabel message2Label = new JLabel("Die empfangene Nachricht: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_message2Label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_message2Label.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_message2Label.gridx = 0;
        gbc_message2Label.gridy = 0;
        gbc_message2Label.weightx = 0;
        gbc_message2Label.insets = horizVertInsets;
        task2Panel.add(message2Label, gbc_message2Label);

        message2TextArea = new JTextArea();
        message2TextArea.setEditable(false);
        message2TextArea.setFocusable(false);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_message2TextArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_message2TextArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_message2TextArea.gridx = 1;
        gbc_message2TextArea.gridy = 0;
        gbc_message2TextArea.weightx = 0;
        gbc_message2TextArea.insets = message2TextAreaInsets;
        task2Panel.add(message2TextArea, gbc_message2TextArea);

        final JLabel solution2Label = new JLabel("Divisionsrest: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_solution2Label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_solution2Label.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_solution2Label.gridx = 0;
        gbc_solution2Label.gridy = 1;
        gbc_solution2Label.weightx = 0;
        gbc_solution2Label.insets = horizVertInsets;
        task2Panel.add(solution2Label, gbc_solution2Label);

        solution2TextField = new JTextField();
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_solution2TextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_solution2TextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_solution2TextField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_solution2TextField.gridy = 1;
        gbc_solution2TextField.insets = message2TextAreaInsets;
        gbc_solution2TextField.weightx = 1; // important
        task2Panel.add(solution2TextField, gbc_solution2TextField);

        final JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel("Ist das übertragene Polynom fehlerbehaftet?");
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_questionLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_questionLabel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_questionLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_questionLabel.gridy = 2;
        gbc_questionLabel.weightx = 1;
        gbc_questionLabel.insets = horizInsets;
        task2Panel.add(questionLabel, gbc_questionLabel);

        questionCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        questionCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_questionCheckBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_questionCheckBox.gridx = 1;
        gbc_questionCheckBox.gridy = 2;
        gbc_questionCheckBox.weightx = 0;
        task2Panel.add(questionCheckBox, gbc_questionCheckBox);

        add(task2Panel);

        add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));

        // Save Panel
        final JPanel savePanel = new JPanel();
        final GridBagLayout gbLayout_savePanel = new GridBagLayout();
        savePanel.setLayout(gbLayout_savePanel);

        locationTextField = new JTextField(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_locationTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_locationTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_locationTextField.gridx = 0;
        gbc_locationTextField.gridy = 0;
        gbc_locationTextField.weightx = 1;
        gbc_locationTextField.insets = horizVertInsets;
        savePanel.add(locationTextField, gbc_locationTextField);

        browseButton = new JButton("Durchsuchen...");
        browseButton.setEnabled(false);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_browseButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_browseButton.gridx = 1;
        gbc_browseButton.gridy = 0;
        gbc_browseButton.weightx = 0;
        browseButton.setMargin(buttonMarginInsets);
        savePanel.add(browseButton, gbc_browseButton);

        saveButton = new JButton("Speichern");
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        final GridBagConstraints gbc_saveButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_saveButton.gridx = 2;
        gbc_saveButton.gridy = 0;
        gbc_saveButton.weightx = 0;
        saveButton.setMargin(buttonMarginInsets);
        savePanel.add(saveButton, gbc_saveButton);

        add(savePanel);

        setResizable(false);
        setSize(450, 287);
        setVisible(true);

        // add listeners
        loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (browseButton.isEnabled())
                    unload();
                else
                    load();
            }
        });

        browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
            {
                final File path = new File(locationTextField.getText());
                final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(path);
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(getParent()) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                    locationTextField.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void load()
    {
        generatorTextArea.setText("10111");
        message1TextArea.setText("10101111");
        message2TextArea.setText("10010010110");
        browseButton.setEnabled(true);
        saveButton.setEnabled(true);
        questionCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(saveButton);
        solution1TextField.requestFocus();
    }


    private void unload()
    {
        browseButton.setEnabled(false);
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(loadButton);
        message1TextArea.setText("");
        generatorTextArea.setText("");
        questionCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GridBagLayoutProblem();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `GridBagLayout`. The `GridBagLayout` allows you to define cells to position components.

So in your example you would basically have two columns and multiple rows. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

For the JSeparator you can specify the component to take up the width of 2 columns. For the last row you would need to create a separate panel for the two buttons and then add the panel to a cell on the main panel using the `GridBagLayout`.

The main point is that you can use nested panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.

> As you see the layout of top and bottom panels should be independent from the centering.

And I addressed this in my answer. your create a panel, probably using a simple FlowLayout (either right aligned or left aligned), add the components to the panel and have the panel span multiple columns.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. I am actually using `GridBagLayout`

Comment: @DannyLo, it doesn't change my answer. The `GridBagLayout` should be for the main panel. I don't think you need a BoxLayout. The problem is with your constraints and/or the lack of nested panels, based on what I can tell from the picture. Since you have posted a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem we can't much help with the code.

Comment: Added a SSCCE. I tried to keep the example as small as possible which is not easy for UIs assembled programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably see it from my example - I almost got the layout to the point where I can be satisfied with it. Now I finally finished the UI. The crucial point, which I was missing before I asked this question, was [camickr's sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405868/1851290) about nested panels. I overthought the usage of nested panels in my code and It turned out I was using too much panels! So I thrown away three single panels which should have the common middle point (`generatorPanel`, `task1Panel` and `task2Panel`) and replaced them with one panel I called `midPanel` The rest (setting constraints, etc) was easy from this point.